# javascript setting and retrieval of cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am being returned "-1". Not sure if i am creating incorrectly (cookies exist and are listed at 161 or so), but not sure if mine is in this group.

```
<html>
<body>
 <div id="cookieLaunch" onClick="cM()">abcdef</div>
<script>
 function cM(){
 var cookie_date = new Date ( 2011, 01, 15 );
document.cookie =  'ppkcookie1=testcookie; expires='+ cookie_date.toGMTString()+'; domain=myDomain.com';
alert(document.cookie.indexOf('ppcookie1='));
}
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

---

Solved
I was trying to find the cookie in a way that was not finding it.
personal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra or missing k in ppkcookie or ppcookie.  :)
Here you have ppkcookie:

```
document.cookie =  'ppkcookie1=testcookie; expires='+ cookie_date.toGMTString()+'; domain=myDomain.com';
```

And here you have ppcookie:

```
alert(document.cookie.indexOf('ppcookie1='));
```

Comment: yep. dumb typo and also realized a better method to find. thanks very much though.